# SN 12.52 Upadana Sutta

Tags: attachment, craving

Can one elaborate please more on this quote:

> "In one who keeps focusing on the allure of clingable phenomena (or: phenomena that offer sustenance = the five aggregates), craving develops.
>
> "Now, in one who keeps focusing on the drawbacks of clingable phenomena, craving ceases."

[Upādāna Sutta SN 12.52 (S ii 84)](http://www.buddha-vacana.org/sutta/samyutta/nidana/sn12-052.html)

How is this exactly done?

Comment: "Makes no sense, makes no sense, does not last, is no refuge, not worthy to fall for, not worthy to harm... to get in debt"

Answer (score 0):

Well that the big question. The general answer is the eight fold path. A more precise answer would be yoniso manasikara https://suttacentral.net/sn46.24/en/sujato
and here there is the condition for this https://suttacentral.net/an10.62/en/bodhi

yoniso manasikara is really just a fancy word for what you quote, ie this

> Even so in him who contemplates the misery that there is in all that
>   makes for grasping, craving ceases.
>
> When craving ceases, grasping ceases.
>
> When grasping ceases becoming ceases.
>
> When becoming ceases birth ceases.
>
> When birth ceases decay-and-death ceases.

For more an ''drawbacks'', you can read all those suttas
http://www.buddha-vacana.org/gloss.html#adinava

> ādīnava: disadvantageous characteristic of phenomena, danger,
>   drawback, disadvantage, bad result or consequence. The antonym is
>   ānisaṃsa. The ādīnava of a particular dhamma is often described as its
>   characteristics of anicca, dukkha, and the fact that it has
>   'vipariṇāma·dhamma'. This is seen mainly in the case of each of the
>   five khandhas (e.g. SN 12.26) and the twelve āyatanas (e.g. SN 35.13
>   and SN 35.14).
>
> ♦ Frequently mentioned in conjunction with assāda and nissaraṇa, often
>   preceded by samudaya and atthaṅgama, as characteristics to be
>   understood in detail for all saṅkhāras.
>
> ♦ This set of 3 or 5 investigations appears very often in the Saṃyutta
>   Nikāya, and is applied to a large variety of dhammas, among which
>   notably to kāma (in detail at MN 13), but also to duccarita (e.g. AN
>   5.241), the five khandhas (e.g. SN 22.74), particularly vedanā (e.g. MN 13), rūpa (e.g. MN 13), the 4 paccayas (e.g. SN 16.1), bhava (e.g.
>   AN 4.10), the six phass·āyatanas (e.g. AN 4.10) etc.
>
> ♦ A very useful statement is made at SN 12.52: 'Upādāniyesu dhammesu
>   ādīnav·ānupassino viharato taṇhā nirujjhati'.
>
> ♦ ādīnava·saññā is defined at AN 10.60 with reference to kāya.
>
> ♦ On the ādīnava of kāma, MN 54 provides a powerful series of similes
>   to describe them, which is referred to in a number of suttas.

Answer (score 0):

> In one who keeps focusing on the allure of clingable phenomena (or: phenomena that offer sustenance = the five aggregates), craving develops.

Like this: mmmm, she is so sexy, the way she looked at me, wow, it's like she's begging for... Something around her eyes... And she's so small... I imagine how she would... If only I could... I feel the pull when she's near. She's so sweet, I almost want to bite her. Etc.

> "Now, in one who keeps focusing on the drawbacks of clingable phenomena, craving ceases."

Like this: I've been through this before. She knows she's sexy and is using it. She's definitely very manipulative. If I lose control she'll take advantage of me. I will get in trouble. I'll lose everything I have: job, family, my stable life. And for what, for that same age old slimy game of moving in and out? She's probably not even smart. What would we even talk about? Besides, I hate losing control. I don't like when my head is spinning and I can't focus because of a woman. I like my normal sober mind. I don't want to be lost again, like that last time. Etc.

Simple, right?

Answer (score 0):

People always cling to the pros hate to the cons.

If people always focus on the cons, anicca dukkha anatta, of five aggregates, they all are going to enlighten surly.

Answer (score 0):

Focusing on drawbacks (of sensual pleasures) is in [MN 13](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.013.than.html), [MN 54](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.054x.than.html), MN 19, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Simply it says, if you see phenomena as advantageous or attractive then carving will follow. If you see the disadvantage of it craving it will cease.

Answer (score 0):

Desire, clinging, cravings, this can be said another way often overlooked: Addiction. Addiction is a desire or habit that's bad for you or others. Lots of what we see are misunderstood as other things. Like anger. Anger isn't just anger. It's desire and a misunderstanding of attachment. Anger poisions the body and mind. Jealousy is a similar missing understanding. As the result of the five come they eventually become bitter because we're attached. Or better addicted. Not unlike a drug. When we don't have it we become sick so we chase after pain relief. All or nothing thinking, Black and white, bartering and deal making an pure dental is synonymous with drug abuse, love addiction and mental health crisis. Breaking these artificial and unhealthy bonds are the point. Emancipation is in it's self a high and mentioned through sutra too. Extremes are not advised. make little changes and building up the 8fold are to get you where your going.You'll always be victim to cause and effect......

Answer (score 0):

What one gives frequent attention that becomes the inclination of mind.
If one is constantly focusing on the pleasant aspects, ignoring the unpleasant aspects, one comes to relish the good and resolves on acquisition of phenomena which are to an extent associated with what one ignores which is the stress associated with those phenomena. Given that the bad associated with phenomena is still there whether one focuses on it or not, one like this is one who relishes the bad and is giving attention to what is inappropriate and is resolving on stress due to inappropriate giving of attention which becomes an inclination of mind due to frequent giving of attention.

Craving is natural outcome here because one who resolves on stress won't be happy and satisfied when facing it and will be longing for an escape due to discontentment. Averse to stress, desiring happiness, craving sprouts.

> "If one is asked, 'From what requisite condition does clinging come?' one should say, 'Clinging comes from craving as its requisite condition.'
>
> "If one is asked, 'Is there a demonstrable requisite condition for craving?' one should answer, 'There is.'
>
> "If one is asked, 'From what requisite condition does craving come?' one should say, 'Craving comes from feeling as its requisite condition.'
> https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.15.0.than.html

Thus clinging is the attachment to, the holding on to and relishing, the tendency to relish due to inappropriate giving of attention and perception of attractiveness.

Answer (score 0):

This is the proverbial monkey trap. If you remember the story, a hunter puts an apple in a jar with a narrow opening, then ties the jar to a tree. When a monkey wanders by and sees the fruit, it will reach its arm in to grab it. But the neck of the jar is too narrow for the monkey to pull out its fist *with* the apple. So, as long as the monkey is focused on the sweet allure of the apple, it will not let it go; it is effectively trapped by its own grasping fist. on the other hand, if the monkey can see that the jar is a trap, the allure of the apple fades; the monkey can release the apple and draw its arm out, and thus set itself free.

In our case, karma is the trap, and its our grasping that locks us into patterns of cause and effect.